# React AntDesign Menu Sub Item ... make it work like component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, menu, antd

For the AntD menu ... we utilise `<Menu>`, `<Menu.Item>`, `<SubMenu>`.

But I don't want to use these for navigation but rather for representation. I want to display the attributes of an object using a dropdown as such.

For eg. Apple -> red, fruit; Cucumber -> green, vegetable; would be displayed as a menu with Apple and Cucumber as the Submenu headings, and the dropdowns for each would be red, fruit and green, vegetable respectively.

But I don't want to predefine attributes and Submenu headings. If it was a component (cards for example), I could've made the component render per object, so that if there were 10 objects, 10 cards (for example) would be rendered.

Is it possible to do the same for `<SubMenu>` and `<Menu.Item>` where I send the data and it first looks at the key 'Name' and renders as a Submenu Heading and renders attributes individually as Menu Items within the Submenu?

Are there any alternatives I can make use of?

---

Not sure If my question is very clear ... I'm happy to clarify anything if confused.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Menu } from "antd";

const { SubMenu } = Menu;

const data = [
  {
    Name: "Apple",
    Colour: "red",
    Type: "fruit"
  },
  {
    Colour: "green",
    Type: "vegetable",
    Name: "Cucumber",
    Season: "spring"
  },
  {
    Name: "Book",
    Title: "hello",
    Author: "nick"
  }
];

const Sider = () => {
  const [openKeys, setOpenKeys] = React.useState(["sub1"]);

  const onOpenChange = (keys) => {
    const latestOpenKey = keys.find((key) => openKeys.indexOf(key) === -1);
    if (data.indexOf(latestOpenKey) === -1) {
      setOpenKeys(keys);
    } else {
      setOpenKeys(latestOpenKey ? [latestOpenKey] : []);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Menu mode="inline" onOpenChange={onOpenChange} style={{ width: 256 }}>
      {data.map((each) => (
        <SubMenu key={each.Name} title={each.Name}>
          {Object.entries(each).map(
            ([key, value]) =>
              key !== "Name" && (
                <Menu.Item key={each.Name + "-" + key}>{value}</Menu.Item>
              )
          )}
        </SubMenu>
      ))}
    </Menu>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Sider />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

CodeSandbox [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-submenu-antd4155-0fc45)

Let me know if this works for you